# Infer type of callback argument

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I cannot get the compiler to know a type of a callback argument.

```typescript
function test3(fn: (foo: string) => any): any;
function test3(fn: (foo: string, payload: number) => any): any;
function test3(fn: (foo: string, payload: number) => any) {

}

test3((foo) => 1); // Ok, typescript knows "foo" is a string
test3((foo, payload) => 1); // KO, typescript does not infer "foo" nor "payload" type
```

I don't understand why on the second call, i'd have to manually write the type of foo, but not in the first call.

Can the infer work with these overloads ? If yes, how ? If not, why does it not work ?

Comment: Seems that `test<any>((foo, payload: any) => 1);` also correctly infers `foo` as a string.

Comment: You've edited the question a couple of times to make the answer "Use an optional parameter instead" not a correct answer to the question, focussing on a requirement to achieve it with overloads instead. **Why** with overloads rather than an optional parameter? What is the advantage? Use the right tool for the job. To be clear: I'm not asserting there isn't or couldn't be a reason for doing it, I'm asking what that reason is. :-)

Comment: *(Side note: It's generally frowned upon to edit a question such that the edit invalidates existing answers based on the previous version of the question. Just for future reference...)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please do not see any offence in this. I think that indeed your answer responded to my original post. But I do not want to take it for granted, as I still do not understand why Typescript works this way, and this is what i want to know. So sorry for making you lose your time.

Comment: @JeanFoin - Don't worry. :-) Fundamentally, "why is it this way" isn't a good fit for SO's Q&A format. It's a bit like "how long is a piece of string?" Probably the compiler doesn't handle modelling an optional parameter via function overloads very well because the compiler expects you to use optional parameters for optional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// change the order for more specific type first
function test3(fn: (foo: string, payload: number) => any): any;
function test3(fn: (foo: string) => any): any;
function test3(fn: (foo: string, payload: number) => any) {

}

test3((foo) => 1);
test3((foo, payload) => 1);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygZgBTDALkVzjkIwCcYwBzAGkQAcBDATwBs4mATQsEAWwBGKcgEpEAXgB8iJmBajCclgG4AUKEiwEydFlwEiwEmSiUa46bPmLrqjeGjwkqDDjyFipRBSp1GrBzcvALCYpIyyuIA3mpqAL5xrvpeljIAjKLqyThe9MzsnFxpiJkqQA)